# How to arrange MySQL columns in ascending order?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a scraper that stores data into MySQL.

It created columns dynamically as soon a new data field is found.

My table usually ends up having 70-100 columns.

I then export this data using phpMyadmin OR Navicat.

but all columns are not properly arranged and makes it really hard to read.

Is there any way to sort/arrange columns in MySQL?

I know there are some answers posted on SO arranging on column, thats not what I want.

I am also willing to write my own small script to export data into CSV/Excel (using PHPExcel). But I will if I find a way to arrange `SELECT`ed data according to column names.

Comment: The question appears to be about formatting, not the actual query. What are you actually looking at? A mysql dump? phpmyadmin in a browser? As a side, a flat table with 100 columns full of null values is unlikely to be the best design

Comment: get associative array from mysql and sort in php using keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with two separate queries. First one will get all columns of given table

```
select column_name from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'your_schema' and table_name='your_table'
order by column_name
```

and then use the output as column definition in your select

```
SELECT implode(', ', $columns) FROM ... (php example)
```